# Why does Google Chrome require a Force Quit when Restarting OS X

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, google-chrome

I am very rarely able to close Google Chrome on my Macbook Pro without force quitting the application. Is there a way to detect why this is happening?

Comment: Chrome sounds fairly buggy based on the many recent posts I've seen related to it :(

Comment: Does it just take a long time?

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure, it's possible, but after several minutes I usually force quit it.

Comment: Do you have Warn Before Quitting turned on? If not, how many tabs do you usually have open?

Comment: @timothymh I do have that feature turned on and usually I have about 5-8 tabs open, one of them being Gmail.  Usually I leave the browser on for days. I'm wondering if this has anything to do with flash.  I notice that loading up flash on my mac is really laggy.

Comment: @Chris It could also be the WBQ setting. Try turning that off and see if it changes anything. I don't expect it will; I've found that if I've left Chrome open for more than a week or two at a time it just does that. I've simply learned to restart it on occasion.

Comment: Might be a memory issue, if you have a lot swapped out.

Answer (score 1):

- What Extensions do you have installed in Google Chrome?
- Check for updates for Google Chrome - By going to Help > About Google Chrome, and the application will automatically check for updates.

If none of the above work, remove Google Chrome and re-install it (check or any saved passwords etc., before removing Google Chrome).

Answer (score -1):

Yes try checking in the Console application logs for a crash reporter log for Google Chrome.

Additionally I would try pulling the Preference files relating to Google Chrome to verify if there is a problem with corrupt preferences that Chrome is having trouble with.

Comment: What do you mean by "pulling the Preference files"?  Do you mean delete them so that they are recreated?

Comment: Sorry I mean move them to a temporary location so that you can restore them later if it turns out the issue continues with the files removed. This is so you don't loost any settings you may have set in Chrome.